# Handling different event types in Java BlockingQueue

Tags: java, generics

I would like to be able to send different events on the same `BlockingQueue`, the events will just carry data.
Given I have the following code:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Event> queue;
class EventA {private long data1;}
class EventB {private String otherData1;}
```

How can I send both `EventA` and `EventB` on the same queue and then let the receiver take care of casting to the right object?

I have tried the following:

1. Make an interface called Event but that fails since I dont want `EventA` and `EventB` to have the same fields.
2. Make queue take an `Object`, this just feels wrong and to general.
3. Send the data in a Map with a special field called type, this also feels wrong.

My question is: What is the idiomatic way of handing this case in Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

> Make an interface called Event but that fails since I dont want EventA and EventB to have the same fields.

An interface does not dictate which fields the classes implementing it will have, only methods.
Since each event type carries more than one data field, it will be more complicated than to just have a generic type of `Event` (for instance, `Event<String>`).
you would have to define an Interface called "Event" and in it 1 method "`Map<String, ?> getData()`" and have each event type implement that method.

the consumer of the events does not have to know what is the concrete event type it is handling. if you do want to use "`instanceof`" conditions, your interface could have a "`String getType()`" method that each event would implement and return it's "name", but that is quite ugly design as it would require more code changes as you add more event types.